# Display modal after submit button clicked/while confirmation page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a MVC web application where the user fills out a form and, after clicking the submit button, a view with a PDF is generated containing the user's information. The PDF generator I am using takes a long time to work, so I would like to have a "Please Wait" modal display when the user clicks submit and waits for the next view to be generated.

The purpose of the modal is to discourage the user from clicking the submit button multiple times, and let the user know that their form went through and the app is still working.

I have tried the following code, but the modal isn't displaying:

HTML

```
<div class="form-horizontal">


   <!--the entire form...-->


   <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="submitButton" />
   </div>


   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="waitingModal" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <h2 class="modal-realtitle">Thank You for Your Patience!</h2>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".form-horizontal").submit(function () {
        $('#waitingModal').show();
    });
});
```

The form is still submitting, but the modal is not displaying. I've also tried this code for the modal:

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#waitingModal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" />
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="waitingModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header"></div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                   <h2 class="modal-realtitle">Thank You for Your Patience!</h2>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above gets the modal to display, but the submit button no longer does what it's supposed to do. In other words, the modal displays but the form does not submit.

This is the first time I am working with modals and trying to make this happen. Is it possible to make the first piece of HTML to work with some jQuery?

Comment: What happens if you use your second example (the one with data-toggle="modal"), but also apply a `$('#submitButton').submit();`? Does the form get submitted?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to work. I have jQuery Validate working on this MVC application and that approach seems to override all of the front-end validation.